# Creating webservice (JAX-WS) with functions which return custom types

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, tomcat7

I read many threads about this issue and i did find some that deal with it - but unfortunately  I couldn't really understand how to solve my problem.

Right now i'm creating WebService (using Tomcat 7), and I want to share interfaces.
I have about 8 interfaces that relate to each other. for example:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
interface A {
  public String method1();
}

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
interface B {
  public String method1();
  public A getA();
}

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
interface C {
  public A getA();
  public B getB();
}
```

The problem is that after i create the WAR (for interface C) file and i'm trying to deploy the webservice in tomcat, I get an error from tomcat which looks like that:

> SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor:
>   com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException:
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions com.mkyong.ws.ITest is an interface, and
>   JAXB can't handle interfaces.     this problem is related to the
>   following location:       at com.mkyong.ws.ITest
>
> com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException:
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions com.mkyong.ws.ITest is an interface, and
>   JAXB can't handle interfaces.     this problem is related to the
>   following location:       at com.mkyong.ws.ITest

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return an interface type using JAX-WS. Return-types and parameters must be an actual class. RMI would support interfaces for that. JAX-WS doesn't.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
In the end my client for the webservice will be an Android application, RMI doesn't work on Android and in many threads i saw that people suggest to use webservice and soap to make a server-(android)client. do you have an idea how to share (make a server) those 8 interfaces that relate to each other with an android client?
thanks.

Comment: You can still us interfaces but the return type must be the concrete implementation. It cannot be an abstract type or interface.